ModuleNotFoundError when Module is apparently installed, Django
My final project for my Python course is making a Pizza website using Django.
I have the init.py, forms.py, main.py, manage.py, models.py, myapp.forms, settings.py, and a README.md, according to what Tabnine said I needed to run this.
Every time I go to launch the website, instead of being able to access it on 127.0.0.1:8000, it doesn't launch, and at the end, it keeps giving me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myapp.forms, despite it being there, installed as correctly as I can tell with Pylint, and I am at a loss.
Contents of the README:
PizzaProject/
├── myapp/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py  # Your OrderForm should be here
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── PizzaProject/
├── manage.py
└── settings.py

apps.py:
"""
This module defines the configuration for the myapp Django app.
"""

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    """
    Configuration class for the myapp Django app.
    """

    name = 'myapp'

forms.py:
from django import forms
from django.db import models  # Import models from django.db instead of django.models

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for creating and updating Order instances."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class for OrderForm."""

        model = models.Model  # Use models.Model instead of django.models.Model
        fields = ['pizza', 'toppings', 'customer_name', 'customer_phone']


main.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from myapp.forms import OrderForm
from myapp.models import Pizza, Topping

def menu_view(request):
    """View function for the menu page."""
    pizzas = Pizza.objects.filter(is_available=True)
    toppings = Topping.objects.filter(is_available=True)
    return render(request, 'menu.html', {'pizzas': pizzas, 'toppings': toppings})


def confirm_order_view(request):
    """View function for the order confirmation page."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.calculate_total()
            order.save()
            form.save_m2m()  # Save ManyToMany toppings
            return redirect('order_success')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    return render(request, 'confirm.html', {'form': form})


def success_view(request):
    return render(request, 'order_success.html')

A test file, for your thoughts:
"""This module contains test cases for the menu view."""
import django.test

from myapp.models import Pizza, Topping

class MenuViewTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = django.test.RequestFactory()
        Pizza.objects.create(name="Margherita", is_available=True)
        Pizza.objects.create(name="Pepperoni", is_available=False)
        Topping.objects.create(name="Cheese", is_available=True)
        Topping.objects.create(name="Mushrooms", is_available=False)


myapp.forms:
from django import forms
from django.db import models  # Import models from django.db instead of django.models

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for creating and updating Order instances."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class for OrderForm."""

        model = models.Model  # Use models.Model instead of django.models.Model
        fields = ['pizza', 'toppings', 'customer_name', 'customer_phone']


settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',  # Add your app here#
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]


I can include the models.py, but I'm having no issues there, so I may hold onto that so no one can scoop the project up.
After typing "python manage.py startapp myapp" in the project terminal through PyCharm, it attempts to launch the app, but ends by saying, again, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myapp.forms.
Picture of error log
(.venv) PS C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\PizzaProject> python manage.py startapp myapp
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\ME\\PycharmProjects\\PizzaProject']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [16444] using WatchFiles
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\PizzaProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 80, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\PizzaProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\PizzaProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myapp.forms import OrderForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.forms'


I want to be able to connect to the test website through a URL at 127.0.0.1:8000, as I've set it up to do.
If anyone knows why it is behaving this way, I would really, really appreciate the help.

You say class MyappConfig(AppConfig) is in __init__.py, but I believe it should be in apps.py instead.

So make a new file called apps.py? I don't have that one yet.

You already have this file in the myapp folder according to the tree diagram in your README.

Kay, I removed it from init, put it into apps.py, and now I'm worrying it's not referencing apps.py, since I had to make one manually and couldn't locate it through my file explorer/directory.
Regardless, after doing that, I still receive the same error messages: "No module named 'myapp.forms' "

The apps.py file is created automatically when you create the app with python manage.py startapp ....  Your file structure looks incorrect.  How did you create the project?  Did you start with django-admin startproject <name_of_project>?

PyCharm. Just kept adding files with the appropriate file extensions until I felt my bases were covered... Guess I should have done some extra commands when beginning. Should I start over, do those commands first in the Terminal?

I would start over.  Django is supposed to automate much of the initial file generating, etc...  I'd also suggest looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/intro/tutorial01/ instead of Tabnine, at least to begin with.

Last thing: It's saying "startproject" is invalid syntax in my terminal. Do I need to be OUTSIDE the project's directory?

What actual command are you typing?  startproject is not a command of its own; it is an argument to django-admin.

django-admin startproject PizzaProject

And what exact error do you get when you type that command?

You probably didn't create your project correctly. It is recommended to create your Django project using the command django-admin startproject <project_name> .
This should be done in a virtual environment which it appears you are using already. Also you should have Django installed in that environment which I guess you've done. Take note of the period . after the the project_name in the startproject command. It is recommended to use this if you want a neater directory structure see the answer here Using period symbol after django-admin startproject <projectname>. Your project_name directory should come with the files settings, WSGI, URLs etc. and in the root directory, you should see a manage.py file.
You can go ahead and create your app using the command python manage.py startapp <app_name> This will create an app directory with models, views, files etc. this is where you should store your forms.py and your app level urls.py files which you have to create yourself see https://realpython.com/django-setup/
Your error: I am not sure why you have a main.py file, it looks to me like a views.py. It doesn't appear in the directory tree you shared but you included the file and that is exactly where your error is coming from. So you might want to shed more light on that.
Also it appears you want to spin up Django's local web server but you're inadvertently running the command to create a new app. To run the local web server, use the command python manage.py runserver. Ensure you have migrated your models using python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate commands. See the docs.
Do reach out in the comments if you need additional information or help.
